# How to set a realistic scope of my project with a rigid and strict supervisor?

Tags: project-management, manager, time-management, projects, deadlines

I am currently working on an 8 month final project, of which 1 month has already passed. Its for an Engineering Doctorate degree. I have one supervisor and one client(who is a PhD student).

**Situation**

It is really important for me to finish the project on time. The most important reason is that I was recently offered a job and I told them that I will join after 7 months. So if I don't complete the project on time then I might lose this job. Secondly, I am living in a foreign country(All of my colleagues are too) and earn some monthly living expenses from the university. These living expenses will stop exactly after 7 months. So if someone is late with their project then they will not get any living expenses for the remaining number of months. Every year they have two or three such cases.

**Problems**

1. They are not responsible for my project timeline: This is not really a problem but both of them made it clear to me on the first day. In the beginning the supervisor told me that you will be the one driving our discussion sessions and deciding your work for each week. The PhD student also told me that "I am not responsible for protecting the timing of your project and you are responsible for that". So I cannot blame them for any delay.
2. Unwilling to Negotiate: The problem is that my supervisor is not willing to negotiate anything related to scope or requirements. The first time I tried to bring up the issue of scope, he said "We will see near the end of the project what happens". The second time I tried to bring it up he got angry and told me "To be real blunt,this is what I want in the end. If you are worried about your grade then I must tell you that you will be given a fair evaluation".

What does a "fair" evaluation mean? Does it mean I will get the degree but I will work 2 more months after my project timeline without pay and also lose my new job?  In that case, this is not really fair at all.

3. Unrealistic Expectations: Now for some reason I feel like that it might not be possible to complete the three goals of the project on time. It might be possible and it might not be possible. I am not sure of the time because I have not done something like this before. And I think that the supervisor is also not sure of the exact time it will take. For example, When I asked about the first goal then the PhD student said it is really simple and will take around 2 weeks. However, when I started implementing we found out that there were a lot of things to implement just to support the simple thing and it is much longer than just 2 weeks of work.
4. Trying to change directions/ Integrating my senior's work: Furthermore, he also wants me to integrate this project with a senior's project.
   Sometimes they want me to go in a different direction which is again scary for me.
5. They ask me to write down the project goals so that could be used to evaluate my work in the end.

**Solution?**

I am really stressed out about the timely completion of my project. I am currently working really hard and don't even take the weekend off. My colleagues are only working 9 to 5 from Monday to Friday. This is the reason that I am already implementing things while they are still studying papers for their topic.

How should I deal with this so that I complete the project on time? How do I set realistic scope and goals for my project without making this guy angry? How do I make sure they don't ask me to do something in the last two months that would make me late?

Comment: Sounds like a conversation you need to have with your stakeholders.  If you are ultimately responsible for timeline then you need some control over scope or a clearly defined scope before the project is 75% complete.  Unfortunately you are off topic here since this is about navigating an academic environment rather than a typical workplace.  Maybe try at the Academics SE?

Comment: Welcome to the world of work. You call it "stressful", we call it "every day". This is not a new phenomenon, and it's pretty much all opinion and conjecture when being answered. We don't know what makes "this guy angry". We also can't predict what they'll do in the future.

Comment: @Myles I posted it here because my question was more about requirements and scope management.

Comment: @JoelEtherton But can you help me protect my project scope ? You are free to edit my question if you think you can make it better.

Comment: @TuUML: That's just it, I don't think it can be made better. These are the issues we struggle with every day in the working world. The answer is simple. Stand your ground, learn to say "no" when the scope grows too big, and if it really comes down to it, learn how to accept failure as a part of the learning process. Keep in mind, it's not always a negotiation. Sometimes it's a line in the sand.

Comment: @JoelEtherton I can't really argue with this guy as he is ultimately responsible for deciding the fate of my degree. If I piss him off he can find other ways to screw me.

Comment: @TuUML Which is kind of why this belongs in the Academic SE rather than here.  Most bosses have no ability to affect your degree.

Comment: PM would likely close it as too broad.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more about performing a job function than navigating the workplace.  This question my be more appropriate for Project Management SE

Comment: Everyone keeps mentioning scope and goals,which are kind of nebulous. You really should create some form of semi-formal (if not formal) requirements document and get sign off. It will help you identify if people are adding work that you didn't agree to do. This then gives you leverage when new work is requested. Well...I can change the requirements to do xyz but then we'd have to get rid of abc so I can still finish within the necessary time-frame.

Comment: @Dunk The problem is that I dont know what could be done in the given timeframe. I am sure that the objective 1 could be done but not sure about objectives 2 and 3 which were also in the project description. I also dont know how long it will take for each of these things to be done. So I cant just finalize the end goal.

Comment: @TuUML - Step 1 is to determine EXACTLY what is expected out of you. Time is not a consideration while doing this task. You just need to identify in as much detail as can be reasonably captured what needs to be done. Get agreement from the stakeholders that you captured pretty much everything. Of course you'll discover more as you go further but with your requirements document you'll be able to identify if those new discoveries are indeed part of the existing scope or is actually new work. New work gives you negotiating room to not do other work in exchange for doing the new work.

Comment: @TuUML - If you think the work is not reasonable for the time-frame then you'll need to do some sort of schedule. Time estimation is hard. Most of the time, very hard. Unless you work at a company where your job is to basically just do variations of the same thing then that is the problem that everyone runs into when doing estimates. The best advice I can give is to start creating lists of tasks. If you can guess how long a task might take then put down a number. If you have no idea then break down that task into smaller tasks until you can at least guess....

Comment: ...Then double your numbers. Once your done, double your numbers again. You'll still probably have underestimated the amount of work but at least if your schedule is showing 3 years to do the amount of work and you only have 6 months then you can have a discussion about scope with some data to back you up.

Answer (score 4):

First, you make a plan based on the current scope. You observe your progress against the plan. If you won't finish on time, you talk to your supervisor about reducing the scope. In theory, you could increase your workload, but for some reason you've done this right from the beginning, leaving yourself no room for future expansion.

Now your supervisor has rejected attempts to reduce the scope early on, when they were based on no information at all. But if you say to your supervisor

> I have to leave on [date] to start my new job. I may be able to help you in the evenings after that, but you know it will be a lot slower. It's best to pick the things that absolutely must be done, and I will make sure they get done before then.

You are likely to get a positive response. You may get an angry threat to lower your mark. I suggest reacting as though this would be awful and enquiring whether this would mean only an A instead of an A+, or perhaps even as awful as a B? Don't smirk or look relieved. Look like your mark really worries you. But if you are going to pass this course by getting parts 1, 2, and 3 done then you don't need to do parts 4, 5, and 6 to get an A - it's enough to pass. You already have a job lined up! Nobody cares what your actual marks were in grad school after your first job.

They are telling you they won't do anything to help you hit your deadline. So you need to. You need to keep tracking yourself against your goals and against how much time is left. You need to set aside perfectionism and see that being finished is important. Don't encourage them to look for every tiny tweak either. When Part 1 is done, tell them that Part 1 is done and you're moving on to Part 2. If they want endless changes and do-overs for Part 1, ask them if they want those so badly that it's ok not to get Part 3? Yes, they may say your work is poor and you should do **everything**, but then again they may not. You won't know until you ask.